# Go Live using Paypal Smart Buttons

Tags: c#, paypal

I have this in my smart buttons:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>

<script>
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
                {
                    reference_id: "PUHF",
                    description: "Sporting Goods",

                    custom_id: "CUST-HighFashions",
                    soft_descriptor: "HighFashions",
                    amount: {
                        currency_code: "GBP",
                        value: "230.00",
                        breakdown: {
                            item_total: {
                                currency_code: "GBP",
                                value: "180.00"
                            },
                            shipping: {
                                currency_code: "GBP",
                                value: "30.00"
                            },
                            handling: {
                                currency_code: "GBP",
                                value: "10.00"
                            },
                            tax_total: {
                                currency_code: "GBP",
                                value: "20.00"
                            },
                            shipping_discount: {
                                currency_code: "GBP",
                                value: "10"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            name: "T-Shirt",
                            description: "Green XL",
                            sku: "sku01",
                            unit_amount: {
                                currency_code: "GBP",
                                value: "90.00"
                            },
                            tax: {
                                currency_code: "GBP",
                                value: "10.00"
                            },
                            quantity: "1",
                            category: "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Shoes",
                            description: "Running, Size 10.5",
                            sku: "sku02",
                            unit_amount: {
                                currency_code: "GBP",
                                value: "45.00"
                            },
                            tax: {
                                currency_code: "GBP",
                                value: "5.00"
                            },
                            quantity: "2",
                            category: "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                        }
                    ],
                    shipping: {
                        method: "United States Postal Service",
                        address: {
                            name: {
                                full_name: "John",
                                surname: "Doe"
                            },
                            address_line_1: "123 Townsend St",
                            address_line_2: "Floor 6",
                            admin_area_2: "San Francisco",
                            admin_area_1: "CA",
                            postal_code: "94107",
                            country_code: "UK"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    },
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
            // Call your server to save the transaction

        });
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

I have logged into my sandbox paypal account to see if the test money went through which it did.
But how to i make these smart buttons go live?

What do i need to change?

Also if i use the smart button to enter credit card details does the user have to have a paypal account in order to pay by credit card using smart button for credit cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To go live, change the `client-id` to one from the 'Live' tab of an
  App at
  https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications
- The Debit/Credit card button will usually expand into a card form that does not require an account